# when i call php file using POST method it returns success even if the nested runs depending upon the outer if-else

Tags: ajax

I've posted code too... When nested else inside if condition runs... ajax success function worked... but else is a false condition it should run failure function

//This is AJAX code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btn').click(function(){
    var name = $('#un').val();
    var pwd = $('#pass').val();
    if (name == "" || pwd == "") {
      $('#result').html('<span style="color:red;">All Fields Are Required!</span>');
    }else{
      $.ajax({
        url: "data.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
        success: function(Text){
          $('form').trigger("reset");
          $('#result').html(Text);
        },
        error: function(Text){
        $('#result').html(Text);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

//This is PHP File's Code

```
 if (isset($_POST['un']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
         if($_POST['un'] == 'Faizan' && $_POST['pass'] == 'abc123'){
            echo "Credentials Matched";
         }else{
            echo "Not Matched!";
         }
     }
```

When username and password doesn't matched it should run failure function in AJAX code but in reality success function runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The success and error functions do not have anything to do with your PHP code. The success function is only called if the request succeeds and the error functions is only called if the request fails.

> **success**
>
> Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR ) A
>   function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets
>   passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted
>   according to the dataType parameter or the dataFilter callback
>   function, if specified; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR
>   (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the
>   success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will
>   be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.
>
> **error**
>
> errorThrown ) A function to be called if the request fails. The
>   function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x,
>   XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that
>   occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible
>   values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error",
>   "abort", and "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown
>   receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found"
>   or "Internal Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can
>   accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn.
>   Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and
>   cross-domain JSONP requests. This is an Ajax Event.Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String

More info you may find here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

In your case the request always succeeds. You either get the return value of the string "Credentials Matched" or "Not Matched!". So what you need is a if statement in your success function, like:

```
...
success: function(text){
         if (text === 'Credentials Matched') {          
            $('form').trigger("reset");
            $('#result').html(text);
          }
          else {
            // Do something else
          }
        }
...
```

Comment: Salaam Brother! it really worked for me... i've some more question can i ask from you???

Comment: Sir firstly i write code same as you in success function but if condition is not working don't know why 

but i fixed it by echo interger in php file 

now this code is working as my requirements... can you please tell what could be the problem when i write same code as yours. Why if condition gone wrong every time???

Secondly i want to redirect my page when credentials matched... what will i do in ajax for this purpose???

thanks you are good

Comment: @FaizanBinZafar to your first question: What exactly is not working with the if statement of the success function? You must land either in the if statement or in the else statement. If the if statement doesn't match, that means that your string value in PHP is different than your string value in your JavaScript. Please pay attention to upper and lower case.
To your second question: Use `window.location.href = 'http://example.com'` to redirect a page.

Comment: i copied same echo statement in if but doesn't matched may be == and === problem. I fixed it thank you so much...

window.location.href='http://example.com' this will redirect instantly but i want to show some message i:e; "Credentials Matched!" then after this message i want to redirect

Comment: @FaizanBinZafar true, it may because of `===`. The difference between `==` and `===` is that `===` is case sensitive and it's based on data type. That means an integer value and a string value won't match. You could redirect the user after i.e. 3 seconds with `setTimeout()`, like: `setTimeout(() => { window.location.href = 'http://example.com' }, 3000);`